# Esp8266 Arduino IDE setup

Tags: arduino-esp8266

Just installed the esp core off of https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino using the "git version" because there was some file missing when installing using board manager. 
However, the esp board does not show up under "Tools/Board:", neither do the esp examples, which should show up under file/examples in the arduino IDE.

Any ideas?

Comment: I ran into a similar problem earlier today. If you go to Tools > Board > Boards Manager and scroll to the bottom. Do you see "esp8266"? If so, click it and then click the install button. After it's done its thing, restart the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File->Preferences
Enter this value in Additional Boards Manager URLs:
http://arduino.esp8266.com/stable/package_esp8266com_index.json